# fat free crm database schema

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, crm, bitnami

I installed fat free crm using the intsaller provided by Bitnami  https://bitnami.com/download/files/stacks/fatfreecrm/0.13.6-1/bitnami-fatfreecrm-0.13.6-1-windows-installer.exe?with_popup_signin=1

Now what I want to know is I want to see the schema of database of fat free crm.But when I open localhost/phpmyadmin I get only two databases 1) Information schema where there are many random tables and other test which is empty.So my question is how to find the database of fat free crm.This is the link to guide of fat free crm of bitnami  https://wiki.bitnami.com/index.php?title=Applications/Bitnami_Fat_Free_CRM&action=source

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bitnami developer here. It is possible you are not using "root" user to log in phpMyAdmin and in that case you do not have privileges to see the "fatfreecrm" database.

Answer (score 1):

check your mysql user privileges. iF user have not sufficient privileges then it doesn't shows the databases.

Comment: How do  I check for priveleges? Using select user,host from mysql.user;?
I should be having priveleges because I am logging in using the admin username and password

Comment: select * from mysql.user where user='root' and host='localhost' \G @PrabhjotSinghkainth change user & host as yours

Comment: tried select * from mysql.user where user='yagyank' and host='127.0.0.1';getting this -> #1142 - SELECT command denied to user ''@'localhost' for table 'user'

Comment: @PrabhjotSinghkainth means simple, your user name has not privileges. Try login with root user (super user like root@localhost). and give privileges to that user

Comment: @PrabhjotSinghkainth or you can use root user in phpmyadmin for login

Comment: I logged in using root but got no databases.Ran select * from mysql.user where user='root' and host='127.0.0.1' and got-> SELECT command denied to user ''@'localhost' for table 'user'

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/82252/discussion-between-hitesh-mundra-and-prabhjot-singh-kainth).

Comment: @PrabhjotSinghkainth see the chat message- http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/82252/discussion-between-hitesh-mundra-and-prabhjot-singh-kainth